# SecureTextField resets after keyboard dismissal

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, passwords, textfield

`SecureTextField` in SwiftUI resets its content after dismissing the keyboard.

This behavior is not observed with the regular `TextField`. When typing in the `SecureTextField` and then dismissing the keyboard, any entered text is lost upon resuming typing. This behavior is unexpected and inconsistent with the behavior of other text input fields in SwiftUI.

How can I prevent the `SecureTextField` from resetting its content after keyboard dismissal, ensuring that the entered text persists as expected?

```swift
struct PasswordTextField: View {

  var placeHolder:String
  var image:String?
  var label:String

  @Binding var text:String
  @FocusState private var isTextFieldFocused:Bool

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 4) {
      if !label.isEmpty {
        Text(label).customFont(Font.poppinsMedium, size: 15)
          .foregroundStyle(Color.appTextBlackColor)
      }
      HStack {
        SecureField("", text: $text)
          .placeholder(when: text.isEmpty, placeholder: {
            Text(placeHolder).foregroundStyle(Color.appPlaceholderColor)
          })
          .focused($isTextFieldFocused)
          .autocorrectionDisabled(true)
          .textInputAutocapitalization(.none)
          .font(.custom(Font.poppinsMedium, size: 14))
          .foregroundStyle(Color.appTextBlackColor)
          .padding([.leading],16)
          .frame(height: 45)

        if let image {
          Image(image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .foregroundStyle(Color.appBorderColor)
            .padding()
        }
      }
      .frame(height: 50)
      .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
          .stroke(isTextFieldFocused ? Color.appPinkColor : Color.appBorderColor,lineWidth: 2)
      )
    }
    .foregroundStyle(Color.appPlaceholderColor)
    .onTapGesture {
      isTextFieldFocused = true
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
@State private var password:String = ""

VStack(spacing:20){
  CustomTextField(placeHolder: "Phone Number", image: "mobile", label: "Phone", text: $phone)
    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
    .onChange(of: phone) { newValue in
      if newValue.count >= 10 {
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
        phone = String(newValue.prefix(10))

      }

    }

  PasswordTextField(
    placeHolder: "Password",
    image: "password",
    label: "Password",
    text: $password
  )
} .onTapGesture {
  UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. After making some modifications to get it compiling, this isn't happening. You likely have something going on elsewhere that is causing this.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the standard behaviour of secure text fields in both UIKit and SwiftUI.

Comment: How is the 1st section of code related to the 2nd section?

Comment: "SecureTextField in SwiftUI resets its content after dismissing the keyboard."  You mean, `SecureField`?